# Microsoft Health API: Getting Account Creation Date

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm trying to load data from the Cloud API, but I don't know when to start my requests from. In the Device API there is "createdDate" key, but its never populated.

Is there a way to find this information from the API without asking the user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the "createdTime" displaying correctly in my profile when I query the Profile API.

Request:

```
GET https://api.microsofthealth.net/v1/me/Profile
```

Response:

```
{
    "firstName":"John",
    "lastName":"",
    "birthdate":"",
    "postalCode":"",
    "gender":"Male",
    "height":19055,
    "weight":549575,
    "preferredLocale":"en-US",
    "lastUpdateTime":"2016-06-04T00:07:58.950+00:00",
    "createdTime":"2015-10-09T18:26:53.498+00:00"
}
```